# Fixing squeaking dryer

Tags: dryer

My maytag bravos intelidry dryer model # medx500xwo makes a load squeaking noise. I would like to inspect the rollers but not sure how to access them. This dryer has a toe panel.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to take the front off so you can lift the drum out so you can look at the rollers (which seem a very likely cause, or part of the cause, based on my squeaking dryer from last year.) I opted to replace rollers, belt and tension roller, since a kit with all three was not very much more than "just rollers" or "just belt" and less than both separately. Look for a service manual, or sometimes there is a diagram when you find the right parts kit.

This is a video from one parts place (not affilated, but looks like the right model/family and was linked to from that part number.) I Hate Tri-Rings...(discovered those last year when doing mine. Miserable things.)

https://youtu.be/CGbf4_NtBkY

You have to take off the top, the top front, the lower front, the circuit board, the wiring for the door switches, the door... you'll pretty well feel like you are taking the whole thing apart, though that will be a slight exaggeration.